# Converting Layout files to Java in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am facing problem to convert layout .xml files to Java
I fave tried but failed to complete.
I need anyones help to complete it.
Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Here is my layout .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_cheese"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cheese"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just want to convert it to java which i have tried so far:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
    box.setId(c);
    /* from here how to convert those below lines in Java         
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cheese"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    */
```

Comment: Have you tried to refer to the official tutorials that explain how to inflate views?

Comment: No sir i just want to simply do it. Please see my edited code sir. :)

Comment: I dont mean to be rude, but this is a place to help you figure out solutions to your problems, not ask other people to do your work for you.

Comment: @Laith Alnagem: This is obviously not work - but a novice question.  Believe it or not, some people are actually beginners. No need to berate them for asking a beginner's question. You could encourage by explaining how and where to search or recommending a good read / tutorial. Sometimes people just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in a good mood, or I would have just pointed you to Egor's comment; the tutorials are designed to show you the efficient ways to do what you want.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams boxParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
box.setLayoutParams(boxParams);
box.setText(R.string.cheese);

// if you want checkbox change listener
box.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (isChecked){
            // perform logic
        }
    }
};

// if you want on click listener functionality
box.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // perform logic
    }
}

linearLayout.addView(box);
```

Haven't tested it, don't know if it is bug free (may have missed something or done something wrong), but I can tell you that unless you plan on only doing this functionality and no other functionality you REALLY need to read into the basics of Android.

Comment: Nice details answer. A few thoughts: `setText()` accepts resources directly - no need to get the string. i.e.  `box.setText(R.string.cheese)`. More readable IMO. Also setting an `OnClickListener` implicitly sets the `View` to be clickable, making the explicit call redundant.

Comment: @zgc7009 Thanks sir
but i am getting nullpointerException
in here
linearLayout.addView(box);

In addition i remove the checkbox tag in xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

->setLayoutParams(..)

```
    android:text="@string/cheese"
```

->setText(..)

```
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
```

->setOnClickListener(..)

Comment: Sir
in setLayoutParams(..) what should i write for "wrap_content"
and in setOnClickListener(..) what should i write inside it?

Comment: @RazilKala The fact you have to ask those questions is 100% why people are telling you that you should read the tutorials. That stuff is Android 101.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
View layout = ViewInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout, null); //your layout name

LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lay);
CheckBox box = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_cheese);
```

Now the `box` object will have all the properties assigned in the xml.

Comment: Actually sir, i dont to want to use findViewByID of checkbox
i want to create it in java and set its attributes in java.

Comment: Very well, but you should do it this way, this is the proper Android way.